# Force constant of metals - Kohn anomaly

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals, phonons

In *Introduction to Solid State Physics* (Kittel), it assumed the force constant between plane $s$ and $s+p$ $C_p=A\frac{\sin pk_0a}{pa}$ in metals to represent a [Kohn anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohn_anomaly). It says such a form is expected in metals. But I have no idea why. Thinking of typical potential energy-distance curve with one inflection point, shouldn't $C_p$ has only one node? Why only metals have such shape of $C_p$ and thus Kohn anomaly?

I guess there are much complex quantum mechanical principles underlying the Kohn anomaly. Is it possible to explain the reason of that $C_p$ shape and Kohn anomaly in the classical manner?